# Source a file template and output it with set variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, json

I have a sort of json template file like this:

```
# INPUT file.json
{
  "set1":{
          "string1": "${VAR1}",
          "string2": "${VAR2}",
          (...)
         }
}
```

A script collects these VARs values. So, I need to source this json template and output a json.tmp with all variables set.

```
# OUTPUT file.json.tmp
{
  "set1":{
          "string1": "string1_value",
          "string2": "string2_value",
          (...)
         }
}
```

I thought of reading the file then echo it, but it always outputs the tmp file without setting those vars.

```
VAR1=$1
VAR2=$2
# (...)
JSON_IN=`cat file.json`
echo $JSON_IN > file.json.tmp
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find variable names in a template file using Bash/Sed/Awk?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/565012) or [How to replace variable strings in a file?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/302832) or [Replace environment variables in a file with their actual values?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/294835) or [Help with echoing the contents of a file that includes variables](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/436422) etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `envsubst` can do:

The variables must be exported because `envsubst` is a forked process and doesn't know of non-exported variables.

```bsh
export VAR1=$1
export VAR2=$2
envsubst < file.json > file.json.tmp
```

Note, that this will break your `json` validity, if the variables contain characters like double quote (`"`) or newline.

Comment: For now that actually works. But why do I have export those variables?

Comment: `envsubst` is forked and  cannot know of non exported variable.

Comment: Note that this will break (as in create invalid JSON) if any of the variables contain characters that ordinarily needs to be JSON encoded.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `envsubst` would work if the values of your variables are "nice" and does not need to be JSON encoded.  It also requires your variables to be exported.

However, as soon as you have special values in you variables, this falls apart:

```
$ jq . file
{
  "set1": {
    "string1": "${VAR1}",
    "string2": "${VAR2}"
  }
}
```

```
$ export VAR1='line 1
line 2'
$ export VAR2='"hello"'
```

```
$ envsubst <file | jq .
parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 4, column 7
```

Instead, trim off the `${` from the start and `}` from the end of the values in the JSON file and use the remaining string to look up the value in the internal `$ENV` variable (an object holding the environment variables as key-value pairs):

```
$ jq '.[][] |= ( ltrimstr("${") | rtrimstr("}") | $ENV[.] )' file
{
  "set1": {
    "string1": "line 1\nline 2",
    "string2": "\"hello\""
  }
}
```

The `.[][]`  extracts the paths of the values, and `|=` is the update operator.  So the values are updated by finding the values of the environment variables that they correspond to, and replacing them with these values.

With the code above, a string that does not correspond to an existing environment variable will be replaced by `null`:

```
$ jq . file
{
  "set1": {
    "string1": "${VAR1}",
    "string2": "${VAR2}",
    "string3": "${bumblebee}"
  }
}
```

```
$ jq '.[][] |= ( ltrimstr("${") | rtrimstr("}") | $ENV[.] )' file
{
  "set1": {
    "string1": "line 1\nline 2",
    "string2": "\"hello\"",
    "string3": null
  }
}
```